# Getting error while trying to mock middleware

Tags: express, jestjs

I wish to mock cookie-session session middle ware. cookie-session is a npm package. I wish to mock this cookie session because I want to mock the session values which route gets after it is passed from cookie-session. I tried looking for this online but could not find any. I tried changing the order of import, that also did not work around.

I found a few workaround online which says to add another middleware in test, and other says to import keys and import it in tests. I don't think this any good solution. I want to mock it.

My index.js

```
const express = require("express");
const keys = require("./config/config");
const cookieSession = require("cookie-session");
const app = express();
app.use(
  cookieSession({
    maxAge: 30 * 4 * 60 * 60 * 1000,
    keys: [keys.cookieKey],
  })
);

app.get("*", (req, res, next) => {
  if (req.session.user == null) {
    console.log("check");
    res.redirect("/auth");
  } else{
     ...
  }
});

app.get('/user', (req,res) => {
  res.json({
    username: "john"
  })
})

const server = app.listen(PORT, () => {
  console.log("now listening on port ", PORT);
});

module.exports = server;
```

My index.test.js

```
const request = require('supertest');
const app = require('../index');

const cookieSessions = require('cookie-session');

jest.mock('cookie-session');

afterAll(() => {
    app.close()
})

describe('app', () => {
    it('test', async() => {
        cookieSessions.mockImplementation((req, res, next) => {
            console.log("INSIDE MOCK AND IT IS WORKING!!!! CONGRATULATIONS")
            next();
        });
        const response = await request(app).get('/user');
        console.log(response.body)
    });
})
```

I am getting the following error:

```
TypeError: app.use() requires a middleware function

      15 | app.use(bodyParser.json({ type: "application/*+json" }));
      16 | app.use(helmet.frameguard());
    > 17 | app.use(
         |     ^
      18 |   cookieSession({
      19 |     maxAge: 30 * 4 * 60 * 60 * 1000,
      20 |     keys: [keys.cookieKey],
```

Comment: It's a timing problem. The middleware is loaded _when the module is imported_, but your test double isn't configured _until the test runs_, much later in the process. So the implementation receives the default test double, `() => undefined`.